# sql query help select statements

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a following query:

```
SELECT '-SELECT MONTH' NAME, -1 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'JANUARY' NAME,1 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'FEBRUARY' NAME,2 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'MARCH' NAME,3 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'APRIL' NAME,4 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'MAY' NAME,5 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'JUNE' NAME,6 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'JULY' NAME,7 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'AUGUST' NAME,8 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'SEPTEMBER' NAME,9 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'OCTOBER' NAME,10 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'NOVEMBER' NAME,11 VALUE 
UNION ALL SELECT 'DECEMBER' NAME,12 VALUE
```

which I bind to a dropdown.

I have another query

```
  SELECT MONTH FROM HRMONTHYEARMASTER 
  WHERE LOCKINGSTATUS IS NULL OR LOCKINGSTATUS  <> '05'
```

which gives me only particular months.

My problem is that i want to combine the two queries and get only the name of the month and its value in my resultset.
I dont know how to go about it. Please help..

Comment: The months that i get from my 2nd query , I only want those in my result set. The problem is I get only Month in int from my 2nd query. I need the name as well in my result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTH VALUE,DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))) NAME  
FROM HRMONTHYEARMASTER 
WHERE LOCKINGSTATUS IS NULL OR LOCKINGSTATUS <> '05'
```

This solved my problem. Now I get the Name as well as the int value of a month.

Thanks Guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For union you must have the same coulmn name :

```
 SELECT '-SELECT MONTH' NAME, -1 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'JANUARY' NAME,1 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'FEBRUARY' NAME,2 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'MARCH' NAME,3 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'APRIL' NAME,4 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'MAY' NAME,5 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'JUNE' NAME,6 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'JULY' NAME,7 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'AUGUST' NAME,8 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'SEPTEMBER' NAME,9 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'OCTOBER' NAME,10 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'NOVEMBER' NAME,11 VALUE 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'DECEMBER' NAME,12 VALUE
UNION ALL 
 SELECT MONTH AS NAME, 100 AS VALUE FROM HRMONTHYEARMASTER 
 WHERE LOCKINGSTATUS IS NULL OR LOCKINGSTATUS  <> '05'
```